# Travelport Universal API confirm air booking Agent ID exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, soap, travelport-api

I am working on a travel agency website in MVC4 which is using travelport for flight inquiries, pricing and booking. It working fine untill i proceed to confirm air booking. It's throwing this exception

```
Message From Galileo : Uncaught Service Exception cause:com.cendant.tds.soa.framework.ServiceException: Exception ReturnedERR: AGENT ID - GALILEO
|+With the Dynamic GTID list of:AF86B8
```

This is the agent information that i am setting in my request

```
AgentAction agentaction = new AgentAction()
{
    ActionType = AgentActionActionType.Created,
    AgentCode = "My Agent Code",
    BranchCode = "My Branch Code",
    AgencyCode = "My Agency Code",
    EventTime = DateTime.Now
};
```

Also tried to set `AgentIDOverride` but still getting that same exception. Can anyone guide me how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance

**UDPATE**

here is the SOAPException inner outer XML

```
<!-- INNER XML -->
<common_v27_0:ErrorInfo xmlns:common_v27_0=\"http://www.travelport.com/schema/common_v27_0\">
    <common_v27_0:Code>some numeric code</common_v27_0:Code>
    <common_v27_0:Service>AIRSVC</common_v27_0:Service>
    <common_v27_0:Type>Business</common_v27_0:Type>
    <common_v27_0:Description>Unsuccessful primary host transaction causing reservation failure.</common_v27_0:Description>
    <common_v27_0:TransactionId>some alpha numeric ID</common_v27_0:TransactionId>
    <common_v27_0:TraceId>some alpha numeric ID</common_v27_0:TraceId>
</common_v27_0:ErrorInfo>
<!-- OUTER XML -->
<detail>
    <common_v27_0:ErrorInfo xmlns:common_v27_0=\"http://www.travelport.com/schema/common_v27_0\">
        <common_v27_0:Code>some numeric code</common_v27_0:Code>
        <common_v27_0:Service>AIRSVC</common_v27_0:Service>
        <common_v27_0:Type>Business</common_v27_0:Type>
        <common_v27_0:Description>Unsuccessful primary host transaction causing reservation failure.</common_v27_0:Description>
        <common_v27_0:TransactionId>some alpha numeric ID</common_v27_0:TransactionId>
        <common_v27_0:TraceId>some alpha numeric ID</common_v27_0:TraceId>
    </common_v27_0:ErrorInfo>
</detail>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was some issue with my credentials, after generating the test credentials i was able to perform the request. Apparently my original credentials were inactive which was resulting in this exception which was solved. I know this is late but might be helpful for someone.